# Reversing string input not giving right output

Tags: c++

Here's how I'm going about it:

```
int maxIndex = input.length() - 1;

    for (int index = 0; index <= maxIndex; index++)
    {
        char temp = input[index];
        input[index] = input[maxIndex - index];
        input[maxIndex - index] = input[index];
    }
```

The input is taken in a string variable called input. Now if the size of the input array is 3, the indexes are 0, 1 and 2

According to me there shouldn't have been any problems but testing this gives me:

Input: pli
Output: ili

Why don't the first and last elements get swapped properly?

Comment: `auto reverse = std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());`

Comment: After you fix that, print the resulting string after every iteration...

Comment: @KyleBurns After that's fixed, the string comes out unmodified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. the last assignment uses `input[index]` instead of `temp` on the right hand side
2. You iterate until the index reaches the end, which means every corresponding pair of indices is swapped twice resulting in the original string after fixing just (1.)

```
if (!input.empty())
{
    for (size_t index = 0, index2 = input.size() - 1; index < index2; ++index, --index2)
    {
        char temp = input[index];
        input[index] = input[index2];
        input[index2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why couldn't I figure that out myself :')

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxIndex = input.length() - 1;

for (int index = 0; index <= maxIndex/2; index++)
{
    char temp = input[index];
    input[index] = input[maxIndex - index];
    input[maxIndex - index] = temp;
}
```

This will solve the issue.

Instead of initialising `input[maxIndex - index]` to `input[index]`, we need to initialise it with `temp`.  The reason is that, the value of `input[index]` is already changed in the previous line.

Comment: Result of this is the exact same string

Comment: The result will be the same as the input string.  to reverse the string, we need to iterate until the half of the length of the string

Comment: @JVApen, I have edited the code.  now, the reversed string will be displayed.

Comment: It's never a good idea to mix types of different size and signed-ness.

Answer (score 0):

Use the swap() function for simplicity

```
for (int i=0; i<input.length()/2; i++){
    swap(input[i], input[ input.length()-i-1 ]);
}
```

This will swap everything until it reaches half of the string, essentially reversing your input

Comment: It's never a good idea to mix types of different size and signed-ness.